# AsyncController in MVC2 and T4MVC: can they work together?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4mvc

Async actions in AsyncControllers (in MVC2) have two action methods (ActionNameAsync and ActionNameCompleted) which seem to confuse T4MVC.

If it can't be done with T4MVC, is there a way to disable it from trying to include these methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, async controllers don't currently work with T4MVC.  Here was a thread discussing it: http://forums.asp.net/t/1534619.aspx

Is this causing something to break for you, or is it simply that T4MVC is not available for those methods, but everything else works fine?

Comment: I added an async controller to my project and it is causing it to break now. I'm wondering if one could pass an array on the T4MVC settings to ignore a namespace or a controller name. What is your opinion on this?

Comment: Ideally, we'd fix it so it doesn't cause a break. Could you show what the exact signature of your methods are, and include the complete text of the error you get?

Comment: You are right. The breaking code was due to something not releated to T4MVC.